# index current line in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I was curious if there is a way to index the current line in bash as it might save quite a bit of typing.

e.g.

```
$ command longarg1 longarg2 longarg3 | command2 <something_to_expand_longarg2>
```

I tried !#2  (!# will give expand the contents of the line so far)
However it did not work as it will expand the whole line and then put 2.

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page, **HISTORY EXPANSION** section, **Word Designators** subsection:

> A : separates the event specification from the word designator.

```
$ command longarg1 longarg2 longarg3 | command2 !#:2
```

Comment: I was close :-), only missing the ":". Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not indexing as you have asked, and not ideal exactly, but how about:

- Using the up / down arrow keys to cycle through history
- Selecting the long command with mouse cursor, Ctrl+Shift+C to copy and then Ctrl+Shift+V to paste?

(environment dependent)